# SQL Conditional use of columns in where clause

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

A bit of background.  My company has produced an application that takes a SQL query, then uses the values it returns to produce graphs and K.P.I.s.  In my problem, we are producing a graph to show the total amount of orders broken down by despatch "route" for a specific formatted date.

There are two tables involved, order header (`ORDERS`) and items (`ITEMS`).

The program requires two fields, XAxis and YAxis to be passed to it to produce a graph.  The graph we wish to produce has the Route Reference (Text) as the XAxis and a sum of items as the YAxis.

Complications occur with the route.  The route can be changed by the operations before despatch, the new route is stored in a different field; lets call these `OLDROUTE` and `NEWROUTE`.  If `NEWROUTE` is blank then they are using the `OLDROUTE`.  If `NEWROUTE` has any value then use `NEWROUTE as XAxis`.

The date used in our tables is an integer, in the format YYMMDD.  The code made to generate it dynamically is given as

```
@DATE=(((year(curdate())-2000)*10000)+(month(curdate())*100)+(day(curdate())))
```

This is compared with the field `DESPDATE` to get all orders completed today.

I have a version that works OK, posted below

```
select CASE WHEN ORDERS.NEWROUTE='' then substr(ORDERS.OLDROUTE) else substr(ORDERS.NEWROUTE,1,6) end AS XAxis,  SUM(ITEMS.QUANTITY) as YAxis
FROM ORDERS
join ITEMS
on ORDERS.ORDNUM=ITEMS.ORDNUM
where 
ORDERS.DESPDATE=@DATE    
and ORDERS.STATUS='COMPLETE'
group by CASE WHEN ORDERS.NEWROUTE='' then substr(ORDERS.OLDROUTE) else substr(ORDERS.NEWROUTE,1,6) end
order by CASE WHEN ORDERS.NEWROUTE='' then substr(ORDERS.OLDROUTE) else substr(ORDERS.NEWROUTE,1,6) end
```

This works fine.  Now the complications come when they want to use a different field for a specific route.  So for example: for route (XAxis) = `'PARCEL'` then want to use `ORDERS.ISSUEDATE`, for route `'BOX'` they want to use `ORDERS.PACKDATE` and for everything else they want it to be the same.

So the new code would be something like:

```
select CASE WHEN ORDERS.NEWROUTE='' then substr(ORDERS.OLDROUTE) else substr(ORDERS.NEWROUTE,1,6) end AS XAxis,  SUM(ITEMS.QUANTITY) as YAxis
FROM ORDERS
join ITEMS
on ORDERS.ORDNUM=ITEMS.ORDNUM
where 
CASE WHEN XAxis='PARCEL' then ORDERS.ISSUEDATE=@DATE 
ELSE WHEN XAxis='BOX' then ORDERS.PACKDATE=@DATE
else ORDERS.DESPDATE=@DATE end
and ORDERS.STATUS='COMPLETE'
group by CASE WHEN ORDERS.NEWROUTE='' then substr(ORDERS.OLDROUTE) else substr(ORDERS.NEWROUTE,1,6) end
order by CASE WHEN ORDERS.NEWROUTE='' then substr(ORDERS.OLDROUTE) else substr(ORDERS.NEWROUTE,1,6) end
```

This does not work.  IS actually possible to use different table fields in a where clase case statement?  Are they asking more than we can deliver?

I have tried a similar query using IF instead of CASE but have not had any success with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `OR` in some parenthetical filters:

```
WHERE ((XAxis = 'Parcel' AND Orders.Issuedate = @DATE) OR
      (XAxis = 'Box' AND Orders.Packdate = @DATE))
```

Comment: Looking at the OP's original code, it seems like the OP is doing more than just conditionally selecting rows.

Comment: A very simple idea; it should work but when attempting to run this on the AS/400 Green screen it produces the message "Column XAXIS not in specified tables".  DB2 doesn't seem to like using alias in the where clause.  Seems you have to use a view or a derived table to get round it.  Will have a bit more of a play and see what happens.

Comment: @vice Generally, you can NOT use the column aliases in the beginning of the SELECT in the WHERE. You could, however, duplicate the definition.

Comment: Taking the above suggestions, I modified the XAxis formula to work it out using string functions instead of a case statement.  Then used multiple `OR` in the where clause to get the desired functionality.  Thanks for your help.  For anyone interested the XAxis code is now: `SELECT SUBSTR(TRIM(SUBSTR(ORDERS.NEWROUTE,1,6))||SUBSTR(ORDERS.OLDROUTE,1,6),1,6) AS XAxis` . This is repeated in the where, group and order by clauses.